# May one `inspect` without getting the context?

Tags: ruby, inspect

I thought `inspect` dumps the contents of an object, but I got far more than I understood the object to contain. I was dumping within a `do` ... `end` block. Is there another method similar to `inspect` that gives only what the object contains, or, how might one `inspect` with no context?

Comment: What do you mean by "context"? Please clarify.

Comment: `inspect` does not take context into account, all the extra stuff you are seeing is likely from classes that the object inherits from

Comment: I want to thank all of the answerers. I ran another test case. Now that things are performing in a more sane way, the test was quite illuminating. I was inspecting on a deeply chained structure. But of course, for each reference, though the reference was not a primary reference from the subject structure, inspect nonetheless expanded everything it saw. So each item got inspected many times: once for the primary structure, and once for each reference, producing a LOT of output for even a rather small list of 16 items. Again, a large thank you to Carl, Matheus, and Nimir.

Answer (score 0):

`inspect` is supposed to print a human-readable representation of the object. It is often used in trace statements. By default, it will print the object's class, object ID and instance variables associated with their values. So, it allows you to quickly determine the type, identity and attributes of the object.

Consider also the `to_s` method, which is supposed to convert the object to a string; it will often compose a new string representation using the object's attributes only; it may or may not use all of them.

Both of these methods do not take anything but its receiver into account.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is not a way to  dump the contents of an object, it is merely a string representation of the object, meant to be human readable.

Individual classes or objects may overwrite the behavior of this method to return any string they want. The default behavior is to display the class name, object id, and any instance variables (which are converted to string by calling `#inspect` on each one). This level of recursion, where instance variables are also `#inspect`ed may be why you are seeing more "context" than you are expecting.

If you are looking for a way to dump the contents of an object to a string, so that it can be re-created from that string, you should look at [`Marshal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Marshal.html). `str = Marshal.dump(obj)` attempts to dump the contents of an object to a string, while `obj = Marshal.load(str)` converts the string back into an object.

Another option, depending on the types of objects, is to serialize them using [`JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) or [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, `inspect` is meant for debugging by dumping all content of the object (human-readable representation of obj).

I think you might find `to_yaml` more useful in your case:

```
object.to_yaml
# #=> --- !ruby/object:ObjectType
# attr1 => value
# attr2 => value
# ... etc
```

#### Tip:

I also found adding `puts` before `to_yaml` gives a more readable console output:

```
puts object.to_yaml
```